# On space text conversion from language to another language?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, textbox, translation

I was working on a translator, in which user try to write in English then press the `SPACE` button or hit `ENTER`. The text will automatically transliterated phonetically into another language.

Like [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) or [MyLanguages](http://mylanguages.org/) or below

[image: Translator]

How should I achieve this by using JavaScript, AJAX or jQuery?

***Maybe this question appears to be off-topic but really I want to know how?***

Comment: possible but first try some stuff from yourself

Comment: I am beginner and have no idea about this..

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/wiki/TranslateMethod check this and see whether this helps

Comment: @user3599534 I agree with Govind...you need to try something for yourself because there could be trillions of solutions and it is way too much to cover in such a small space like this. Analyse your project, do some research and then you'll be able to come to a solution that best suits your scenario and budget

Comment: Thanks Leo and Sweetz. but can you hint me which function it uses?. I know about google translate but I want to build my own.

Comment: it uses `keyup` event listener @user3599534, believe me it can have numbers of solutions.

Comment: I tried hard but from your trillions solutions I couldn't find any... :(

Comment: Thanks @VedantTerkar. The rest I will do myself, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do would be as simple as this:

HTML:

```
<input id="name" placeholder="Name" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementById("name");
input.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32)
        alert("Translate"); // Your translation code
};
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/poor6ywn/)**